# What does "msnbot" mean in netstat listings?

Tags: windows-8, netstat

I was checking my Windows 8.1 PC's outgoing connections using the command `netstat 5`, on the [advice of this article](http://www.abuseat.org/advanced.html) to check whether I have botnet problems.

Everything looked normal except this:

[image: TCP connection established to msnbot]

`192.168.8.102:51522` connecting to `msnbot-191-232-139-86:https`

I can't find any clear information about it online and it doesn't correspond to anything I'd expect to be using my connection. Apparently [there's a Microsoft web crawler called msnbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Msnbot), but I can't see any sensible reason why that would be on my machine.

The closest I can find [is this, in Spanish](http://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/qu%C3%A9-es-el-msnbot-established-en-netstat/9c5f345e-c937-4934-b11b-9343c2a0b96c), which seems to suggest that it has  something to do with Windows built-in web search - but I don't use such a thing, whereas this connection is in `netstat` constantly.

Following Jonno's suggestion I ran `netstat 5 -b` from a command prompt run as an administrator, and it gave `explorer.exe` as the owner of that connection.

What is msnbot in this context, and what does it mean if it appears in listings like this? I'm not aware of having any MSN software installed.

Comment: Try adding `-b` to find out what process is using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal, and it does indeed correspond to a `.search.msn.com` address, so it's a legit Microsoft server. Your connection to it is not related to web crawlers, but many claim that it helps retrieve web results from Cortana (in Windows 10) or the Metro search (on Windows 8). It's also been [linked to OneDrive](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cac1a5a1-4bed-47e9-b563-441eeb49a555/explorerexe-permanent-tcp-connection-to-wnswindowscom?forum=w8itprogeneral).

When I navigated to the IP address `191.232.139.86`, Chrome told me that the server's certificate was actually for `*.wns.windows.com`. [WNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187203.aspx) (Windows Notification Services) is the service that lets third-party apps' servers send those apps push notifications.

Don't worry, it's not a virus or spyware; people on the Internet are just freaking out because it has "bot" in the name.

Answer (score 5):

It is the Network Connection Broker service (NcbService) that keeps calling out. Its function is to 'allow Windows Store Apps to receive notifications from the internet'.

Hit 'Win+R' > enter 'services.msc' > locate 'Network Connection Broker' in the list > stop and disable the service and you are good to go!

Comment: Does this address the original question?

Comment: "... I can't see any sensible reason why that would be on my machine ..."
"... What is msnbot in this context, and what does it mean if it appears in listings like this? ..." 

I'd say it does

Comment: Ah okay; is when you're saying "It is the Network Connection Broker service..." you're referring to msnbot? (and where does Brazil come in?)

Comment: About Brazil: For those I've helped with this little annoyance Explorer.exe always phones a datacenter in Brazil (even the IP address Ben N. mentions is located in Brazil but I guess the connection could be made to any of Microsofts datahubs). I'll remove it. 
'msnbot' is just a name, just like 'wns' or 'search' (see hebertuz and Ben N.s' answer). The NcbService is what tells Explorer.exe to make the call.

Answer (score 0):

`"msnbot-65-xx-xxx-xxx:https ESTABLISHED"` is a windows 8 process that wroks on background for search done on windows mostly when you use the search textbox on the windows bar, you notice when you type something it search for windows apps but also gives you internet results, well this process connects to web site `msnbot-65-55-4-23.search.msn.com` to search for the results it display